# New mail alert for shared mailbox outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, vsto, alert, shared

I am trying to create a popup mail alert for a shared mailbox in Outlook 2007.
The following code doesn't work. why?

```cs
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Explorers Explorers;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder mFolder;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Explorers = this.Application.Explorers;         
  outlookNamespace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");         
  mFolder = outlookNamespace.Folders["Mailbox -AdditionalMailBox"].Folders["Inbox"];  
  mFolder.Application.NewMailEx += new  ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx );
}
private void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryID)
{
  MessageBox.Show("New MailReceived!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your event handlers to survive garbage collection - you need to ensure that the objects that contain your events are kept alive by adding them as a private member variable. Try adding an `Application` private class variable and your event subscription should work just fine. See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539705/175679) for more details.

```cs
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    application = this.Application;
    Explorers = application.Explorers;         
    // ...         
    application.NewMailEx += new  ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx );
}
```

The other issue you discovered is that `NewMailEx` only fires for your primary mailbox - not secondary mailboxes as [confirmed in this forum post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/problem-using-newmailex-t3525229.html). You will need to rely on the [`Folder.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.items.aspx) event [`ItemAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemsevents_event.itemadd%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```cs
private Outlook.Items mFolderItems;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    mFolderItems = mFolder.Items; // avoid GC for ItemAdd event
    mFolderItems.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(mFolder_ItemAdd);
    // ...
}        
private void mFolder_ItemAdd(object addedItem)
{
  Outlook.MailItem newItem = addedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
}
```

Comment: Application only subscribes new mail in the primary mailbox. It didn't work for the additional mailbox.

Comment: @ShnerkaZoid - you are correct - `NewEmailEx` only works on the primary mailbox, see edits above.

Comment: @ShnerkaZoid - glad it helped you out! Please accept this as an answer so that others may benefit. =)

Comment: Click the tick (**check mark**) on left under the vote arrows.