# Outlook ItemChange Handler (makes item unchangeable)

Tags: c#, event-handling, outlook, add-in

i write a Outlook Addin which should change an Contactitem after write.
i use ItemChange EventHandler

```
folder.ItemChange += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemChangeEventHandler(ContactItemChange);
```

but when i am editing an item, my Code always run in background and so i can't editing my Item.

I have tried item.AfterWrite and item.Write but the Event will never Triggered.

```
    private void ContactItemChange(object item)
    {
        if (item is ContactItem)
        {
            ((ContactItem)item).AfterWrite += ThisAddIn_Write;
        }
    }
```

Need Help!
Bye
Konobi

Answer (score 1):

Your event registrations are probably getting garbage collected. Make sure `folder` is declared as a private class member and you will also need to manage a private class member collection of `ContactItems` (*`List<ContactItem>` or similar*) to ensure `AfterWrite` event handlers are properly registered and not disposed of.

For reference, see [this SO post which describes VSTO limitations with event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539705/175679) and how to properly attach to Office events.