# Outlook Event is not getting fired on click of custom button

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing a Microsoft Outlook Add-in, where I have added one button in Add-In tab name `OPENISMS`. I could see the button, however on click the event is not getting fired. I have no clue why it is behaving in this manner. Please find below are code for adding button and attaching event to it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```cs
private void AddButtonToNewDropdown()
{
    Office.CommandBar commandBar = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars["Standard"];
    Office.CommandBarControl ctl = commandBar.Controls["&New"];
    if (ctl is Office.CommandBarPopup) 
    {
        Office.CommandBarButton commandBarButton;
        Office.CommandBarPopup newpopup = (Office.CommandBarPopup)ctl;
        commandBarButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)newpopup.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, true);
        commandBarButton.Caption = "OpenISMS";
        commandBarButton.Tag = "OpenISMS";
        commandBarButton.FaceId = 6000;
        //commandBarButton.Enabled = false;
                      commandBarButton.OnAction = "OpenISMSThruMail.ThisAddIn.ContextMenuItemClicked";
        commandBarButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(ContextMenuItemClicked); 
    }

}
private void ContextMenuItemClicked(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    if (currentExplorer.Selection.Count > 0)
    {
        object selObject = currentExplorer.Selection[1];
        if (selObject is MailItem)
        {
            // do your stuff with the selected message here
            MailItem mail = selObject as MailItem;
            MessageBox.Show("Message Subject: " + mail.Subject);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling `AddButtonToNewDropdown()` method from `ThisAddIn_Startup` event.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the `CommandBarButton` a class-member variable in scope - otherwise it will be garbage collected and the event will not fire as you've observed.

```cs
public class ThisAddIn
{
   Office.CommandBarButton commandBarButton;

   private void AddButtonToNewDropdown()
   {
     // ...
   }
}
```

See [related SO post regarding similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539705/175679).

Comment: Great - glad it helped you out. Please mark this as the accepted answer so that others may benefit. Just click on the tick (*check mark*) on left under the vote arrows.